# iOS: image over another rotate image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I have this method to add an image over another image and obtain a merge result

```
- (UIImage*) createImage{
    UIImage *imageToShare = nil;
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view frame]];
    imageView.image = currentImage;
    UIImageView* subView   = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToUse.image];
    [imageView addSubview:subView];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    imageToShare = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [subView release];
    [imageView release];
    return imageToShare;
}
```

it work fine because my imageToShare it's ok, but the problem is that "subView" is an image that I can rotate and pinch for zoom and move...then when I do this method subView return to its original position...what can I do to save it in its state position over imageView?

Comment: What do you try to do? It’s not really clear from your description. If you want to allow the user to further modify the merged image, I would suggest to draw to a non-visible context and then assign the result to the UIImageView image property.

Comment: yes yes... and what's the way to assign the imageView at this non-visible context?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge two images, keep the merged result, and let the user manipulate it further, a good way is to draw to an off-screen context with a specific size, then create a CGImageRef, and then assign it to the image view. Take a look at [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637651/core-graphics-how-to-get-a-cgimageref-from-context-drawn-images) to see how it’s done.

Comment: I follow your suggest but I obtain a black image

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors: both source images, filters, where do you draw them, … It’s tough to give specific advice at this point without having more information, sorry.